# why does the PHP Manual say that fetch() doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

in PHP, it's apparently possible to do the following (when working with a mySQL PDO connection)

```
while ($row = $result->fetch())
   {
                           }
```

---

However, the PHP Manual says that `fetch()` doesn't exist:

[image: PHP Manual says that 'fetch()' doesn't exist]

What's going on? And how can I better learn to navigate the PHP Manual?

Answer (score 1):

The `fetch` function is a member function of `PDOStatement` class. The documentation for the same can be found [here](https://devdocs.io/php/pdostatement.fetch) (DevDocs.io) and [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) (php.net).

Comment: Appreciate the answer. Can you suggest a resource that can teach me how to read the PHP Manual? I find it very overwhelming. Thanks.

Comment: Use devdocs.io link above, it supports fuzzy matching, so you can type in random characters. At the bottom of every page, they provide a link to the actual php.net docs link.